# How to write to a text file from windows forms application

Tags: c#, winforms

I am generating permutations from algorithm and writing same to a text file.,after generating it gives no error but only one permutations is found in the text file.is it encoding problem or something else i am missing.

'''

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        string str33 = textBox1.Text;
        char[] arr = str33.ToCharArray();
        int r = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);
        int n = arr.Length;
        printCombination(arr, n, r);
        }
```

'''

The line which finally writes to the text file goes like this.

'''

```
File.WriteAllText(finalocation, str);
```

'''

where finalocation is the path of the text file and str is the string to be written to it.Anything more required i will reply further.

Comment: Please review [MCVE] guide on posting code and [edit] the question to at least clarify what is the value of `str`... Code as shown will indeed write full content of `str` to the file... Maybe you are looking for way to *append to a file*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store your all permutations in a list and send the list to your designed method to write in file. 
The method for writing should be similar to the following.

```
 public void printToFile(List<string> allPermutations) { 
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("names.txt")){
          foreach (string s in allPermutations){
                    sw.WriteLine(s);
          }
    }
 }
```

Comment: facing difficulty in calling the function .what to pass as a parameter.thanks for your support

Comment: The method should be almost similar to the method I have already given above. You should provide your code so that I can help you better. Also please explain your problem clearly.

Comment: Sorry for the poor input,I was frustrated with the code ,but it worked at last.